# The computer sees no HDD

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, uefi

UEFI doesn't see the internal HDD. I've tried to perform tests via UEFI settings, it says all devices are alright. Could it be caused by wrong/corrupt partitioning or is it a hardware problem.

The output of `fdisk /dev/sda`, `p`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 298.09 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD3200LPVX-0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 625142414 625140367 298.1G Linux filesystem
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is insufficiently documented.

Depending on the way your drive is connected to your mainboard it is perfectly normal that your UEFI bios does not see your drive.

As long as your operation system sees the drive and all data on it there is no need to worry.